# Optimize data looping

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I have a grid of 20,000-150,000 rows and with a click I can select all then I used this call to approve them.
This works for less then 1000 rows, but any more then that the browser locks up and never finishes even after I left it alone for 20min.

I am looking for solutions that will optimize this process .

```
$("#approval").on('click',function(){
    var thisgrid = Grid; //my gridwapper
    var spotrows = thisgrid.grid.getSelectedRows();

    var index = 0;

    // console.dir(spotrows);

    if(typeof spotrows.length == 'undefined' || spotrows.length == 0)
    {
        alert('Please select a spot.');
        return;
    }

     for(key in spotrows)
     {

     var spotupdate = {};

     thisgrid.grid.invalidateRow(spotrows[key]);
     spotupdate = thisgrid.dataview.getItem(spotrows[key]);
     spotupdate['Approved'] = (spotupdate['Approved'] == 1) ? 0 : 1;

     thisgrid.dataview.updateItem(spotupdate['id'],spotupdate);


     }
    thisgrid.dataview.refresh();


});
```

Comment: What is your use case?  Why do you have a grid with 150,000 elements on it?

Comment: Well, you should show your  thisgrid.grid functions to see if its efficient, but 150k items... why so many?

Comment: Break the loop into multiple separate function calls, and use `setTimeout` to call the next function. This way you are giving the JS event-loop a chance to process other queued events (such as UI interaction)

Comment: We are showing the user all imported items. I am using files from 1k-150k and they load up fine as Slick Grid can handle 1 million rows. I just need a good process to approve them all if they need to be batched approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using setTimeout and that did not improve performance.

Here was the solution I used.
After a few tests I took out the following lines out as they seemed to not be needed:

> thisgrid.grid.invalidateRow(spotrows[key]);
>
> thisgrid.dataview.refresh();

and added the very important :

> thisgrid.dataview.beginUpdate();

and

> thisgrid.dataview.endUpdate();

Here is the full code for reference:
This allowed be to update 100,000 rows in a less then 2 seconds.

```
$("#approval").on('click',function(){
    var thisgrid = Grid; //my gridwapper
    var spotrows = thisgrid.grid.getSelectedRows();

    var index = 0;


    if(typeof spotrows.length == 'undefined' || spotrows.length == 0)
    {
        alert('Please select a spot.');
        return;
    }
    thisgrid.dataview.beginUpdate();
    for(key in spotrows)
    {

       var spotupdate = {};

       thisgrid.grid.invalidateRow(spotrows[key]);
       spotupdate = thisgrid.dataview.getItem(spotrows[key]);
       spotupdate['Approved'] = (spotupdate['Approved'] == 1) ? 0 : 1;

       thisgrid.dataview.updateItem(spotupdate['id'],spotupdate);
       delete spotupdate;
       delete spotrows[key];


     }

    thisgrid.dataview.endUpdate();


});
```

Comment: if you answered your own question, please consider making your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the browser is locking up, is because Javascript (and the UI) runs in a single thread. Which means, so long as code is executing, the browser cannot process UI events (clicks, re-draws, etc).

A way you can process large amount of data while still keeping the UI responsive, is by breaking up the loop into multiple smaller function calls, and using `setTimeout` to queue the next loop segment. Something like this:

```
$("#approval").on('click',function(){
    var thisgrid = Grid; //my gridwapper
    var spotrows = thisgrid.grid.getSelectedRows();

    function iterate(rows){
        var max = 1000, count = 0;
        for(key in rows){
            // do stuff

            delete rows[key];
            count++;
            if(count == max) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    iterate(rows);
                }, 0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    iterate(spotrows);

});
```

Even though the timeout it being set for 0 milliseconds, this still works, as `setTimeout` ensures the function is called on the next pass of the JS event loop, thus giving an opportunity for other queued events to be processed.

More on the JS event-loop - http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/